# jpa openjpa - order by with cast

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I am using jpa with openjpa and i have table with varchar that represent as int in object.

column: "TRIES_ERR" (varchar)

Entity:

```
public class Book implements Serializable{

    int triesErrAsInt;
    String eMail

    @Column(name="TRIES_ERR")
    public int getTriesErrAsInt() {
        return triesErrAsInt;
    }
    public void setTriesErrAsInt(int triesErrAsInt) {
        this.triesErrAsInt = triesErrAsInt;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEMail() {
      return eMail;
    }
    public void setEMail(String string) {
      eMail = string;
    }

}
```

I try to write a query with order by `TRIES_ERR` but as `int` and not as `varchar`.

I have to use jpql (and not native query)

This is my query that I try and didn't work:

```
SELECT x 
FROM Book x 
ORDER BY x.triesErrAsInt ASC
```

returned rows are ordered as varchar and not as integer

I get as result: 12,13,14,2,3 instead 2,3,12,13,14

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Yes this is your query try it and post the problem. (if any)

Comment: sorry for the misleading. i fix the question, and i already try it of course

Comment: there is no Exception the order i get as result is 12,13,14,2,3 instead 2,3,12,13,14

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT x from Book x order by cast(x.triesErrAsInt as int) asc
```

Comment: not working.. getting Exception: "Encountered "by"  but expected: ["AVG", "COUNT", "MAX", "MIN", "SUM", <IDENTIFIER>]."

Comment: i was implying you put the new `order by` after the already present `select x from book x`. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: this my Exception: Encountered "cast (" at character 31, but expected: [".", "AVG", "COUNT", "MAX", "MIN", "SUM", <IDENTIFIER>]. (at the first try i wrote by mistake double "by")

Comment: it's possible your JPA implementation doesn't support it. What are you using (hibernate, eclipselink, what version?)

Comment: jpa 1.0. and OpenJPA 1.2.1

Comment: I just had the same problem, it looks like OpenJPA doesn't have CAST, but CONCAT(x.column, '') achieves the same result

Comment: working solution using Spring Data and hibernate, see this link for details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188918/casting-integer-to-string-in-jpql