# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : INT

Tags: java, hql, scrollableresults

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested
>   type for CAST : INT [ SELECT SUBSTRING(referenceComptable , 8, 14) AS
>   seqNum, SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 4,7) AS yearCegid,
>   SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 1,3) AS journal FROM
>   com.dso.model.comptabilite.cegid.EtapeJudiciaireLnkFactureActesHonoraires
>   WHERE dateCegidGenerated BETWEEN :date AND :dateYearIntervalDate 
>   ORDER BY CAST(seqNum AS INT), CAST(yearCegid AS INT), CAST(journal AS
>   INT) ASC ]

HQL QUery:
    public ScrollableResults retrieveSequenceNumberForCegidGenerated(){

```
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(" SELECT SUBSTRING(referenceComptable , 8, 14) AS seqNum, SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 4,7) AS yearCegid, SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 1,3) AS journal")
                            .append(" FROM EtapeJudiciaireLnkFactureActesHonoraires ")
                            .append(" WHERE dateCegidGenerated BETWEEN :date AND :dateYearIntervalDate ")
                            .append(" ORDER BY CAST(seqNum AS INT), CAST(yearCegid AS INT), CAST(journal AS INT) ASC ");

        Query query = getFilteredCurrentSession().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());

        //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        LocalDate yearIntervalDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(365);
        Date dateYearIntervalDate = Date.from(yearIntervalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

        query.setParameter("date", date);
        query.setParameter("dateYearIntervalDate", dateYearIntervalDate);

        ScrollableResults referenceComptable = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
        query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
             .setFetchSize(500);

        return referenceComptable;
    }
```

When i tried to CAST as INT it didn'y work also. What can be done to cast it ffrom string to integer?

Stack Trace

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested
>   type for CAST : INTEGER [ SELECT SUBSTRING(referenceComptable , 8, 7)
>   AS seqNum, SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 4,4) AS yearCegid,
>   SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 1,3) AS journal FROM
>   com.dso.model.comptabilite.cegid.EtapeJudiciaireLnkFactureActesHonoraires
>   WHERE dateCegidGenerated BETWEEN :date AND :dateYearIntervalDate 
>   ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(referenceComptable , 8, 14) AS INTEGER),
>   CAST(SUBSTRING(referenceComptable, 4,7) AS INTEGER), journal ASC ]    at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1825)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]     at
>   com.dso.dao.comptabilite.cegid.impl.ReferenceComptableSequenceDAOImpl.retrieveSequenceNumberForCegidGenerated

Comment: As from hibernate document,"cast(... as ...), where the second argument is the name of a Hibernate type," try using 'int' instead of INT for type matching

Comment: ... or `CAST(... AS integer)`. Note that Hibernate types are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 9):

please replace

```
CAST(xxxx AS INT)
```

by

```
CAST(xxxx AS int)
```

Answer (score -1):

I also could complete as above.

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(<column name >, -3) AS int)
```