# How to query with Spring JPA on jsonb columns?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring JPA with PostgreSQL database. I have an Entity as follow:

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name="json_binary", typeClass = com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.class)
public class LiveTokens {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue()
   private Long id;

   private String username;

   @Type(type="json_binary")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   private Token token
}
```

and `Token`:

```
public class Token {
   private Long expireTime;
   private String accessToken;
}
```

For saving object to column with Hibernate, I use [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project.
Now I want to get All `LiveToken`s that expired. I can't do it with Spring JPA. How do I query to posgresql jsonb column with Spring data JPA?

Answer (score 11):

### SQL JSON functions

If you want to call a SQL function that processes the JSON column, then you just need to make sure you [register the function](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/) with Hibernate prior to using it.

### JSON operators

For JSON operators, like the PostgreSQL ones (e.g., `->>`), the only option you have is to use a native SQL query. JPQL or HQL don't support database-specific JSON operators.

Answer (score 2):

Using EclipseLink and spring data jpa, if your data in db is something like: {"expireTime":102020230201, "accessToken":"SOMETHING" }, my first question is why to use long numbers for your dates instead of timestamps (ex '2019-09-14 12:05:00'). If you use timestamps there are also options to manage timezones (either from postgresql or from you source code).
Regarding your issue you may use the [FUNC JPQL keyword of EclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm) (Hibernate may have something similar) in order to run a database specific function. In the example below I use `FUNC('jsonb_extract_path_text', lt.token, 'expireTime')` to get the values of the json for token.expireTime.
PostgreSql method `jsonb_extract_path_text` returns text, thus you cannot do a less that condition, so I cast the output of the function using [JPQL CAST keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188918/casting-integer-to-string-in-jpql) with `(CAST -data- TO -type-)`.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<LiveTokens, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT lt FROM LiveTokens lt WHERE CAST(FUNC('jsonb_extract_path_text', lt.token, 'expireTime') AS LongType) < :expirirationThreshold")
    List<LiveTokens> findByExpireTime(@Param("expirirationThreshold") Long expirirationThreshold);
}
```

Again, this is not tested.

Comment: this error `Could not resolve requested type for CAST : int8[select lt from ...]`

Comment: The error you get is about the `INT8` type the `CAST` uses. You may replace the INT8 with a different type. You may also try LongType or Long.

Answer (score 1):

This is how a native query using Postgres JSON query operators would look like, incorporating your example:

```
@Query(value="SELECT t.* FROM LiveTokens t WHERE CAST(t.token ->> 'expireTime' AS LONG) < now()", native=true)
```

Assuming your **real** table name is `LiveTokens`, native queries no longer use the JPA translations, and the table name has to match the one in the DB. (You may also need to specify its schema.)

Answer (score -3):

Try it:

Service class:

```
Long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT lt FROM LiveTokens lt WHERE lt.token.expireTime <= :currentTime")

List<LiveTokens> findExpiredLiveTokens(@Param("currentTime") long currentTime)
```